# Promise only resolves on the first request

Tags: node.js, express, promise

I am developing an API to create a warehouse structure. Because we are using a microservice architecture I need to make a request via **rabbitmq** to another microservice to generate the address for the new warehouse.

Therefore I use the **ampq** consume function wrapped in a function which returns a promise. When I hit the endpoint the first time the promise gets resolved and I can continue with my data. But in the second request, the promise will not get resolved.

Maybe it's for an obvious reason but at the moment I don't get it.

So here is my code:

**routes.js**

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  ... 
  const validate = ajv.compile(warehoseSchema);
  const valid = validate(req.body);
  if (valid) {
    sendToQueue('addressMgmt', req.body.address);
    consume()
      .then((result) => {
        const {
          id_address: idAddress,
          license_plate: licensePlate,
          town,
        } = result.body;
        createWarehouseHandler(
          customernumber, req.body, idAddress, licensePlate, town,
        )
          .then((insertId) => {
            res.json({
              id: 'warehouses02',
              message: `Warehouse with id ${insertId} successfully created`,
            });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            res.status(err.status).json({
              id: err.id,
              message: err.message || err.sqlMessage,
            });
          });
      }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(err.status).json({
          id: err.id,
          message: err.message || err.sqlMessage,
        });
      });
  } else {
    res.status(417).json({
      id: 'warehouses01',
      message: `Invalid JSON: ${ajv.errorsText(validate.errors)}`,
    });
  }
});

const consume = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const q = 'warehouseMgmt';
  amqpCh.consume(q, (msg) => {
    const message = JSON.parse(msg.content.toString());
    if (Object.keys(message).includes('body')) {
      resolve(message);
    } else {
      const err = new Error();
      err.status = 500;
      err.id = 'rabbit01';
      err.message = 'No message was cosumed';
      reject(err);
    }
  }, { noAck: true });
});
```

On the first request `consume().then()` gets called but on the second and following requests, it doesn't.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `Promise` can be resolved or rejected only once, this is expected be behavior.

Comment: I know this. But on the second request the consume() function is called and returns a new Promise doesn't it?

Comment: Ensure that `consume` and `amqpCh.consume` are called on second request

Comment: Even on the second call I reach the callback of amqpCh.consume and can see the correct message. But it doesn't get resolved.

Comment: So it is rejected then or nothing happen at all?

Comment: Wrap `const message = JSON.parse(msg.content.toString());` with `try/catch` block and reject on catch

Comment: Nothing happens at all. I wrapped the JSON.parse() but it throws no error and I can see the correct message on the second request when I log it.

Comment: Put `console.log` into first line of `then` and `catch` of `consume`

Comment: Wrap everything inside `amqpCh.consume` with `try/catch`

Comment: What `amqpCh.consume` does? Is that from an npm package? Did you write it yourself? Is some kind of subscriber? Can you share it? My guess would be that `amqpCh.consume` expect some kind of listener and a new listener is not been added every time you call the `consume` function, it could be using the first registered listener so you would be trying to resolve same promise in subsequent invocations.